# hg client and server side hooks

Tags: git, mercurial, githooks, mercurial-hook

What is hg equivalent for git client and server side hooks?

I was trying to find the two different types of hooks for hg like in git, but only found lot of hooks not specific of client or server side. I think hooks cannot be setup on the client side, but I am not sure.

Comment: Mercurial just doesn't see hooks as specifically client-side or server side. Hooks are run regardless. That's because the whole model is *distributed*, your Mercurial repository is both client and server.

Comment: If i setup a hook in my local repo and push with my changes. the hgrc file is not going to be pushed right?

Comment: No, hooks are not propagated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mercurial doesn't divide hooks into 'client' and 'server', because your repository is *both the client and the server*. If you register hooks locally, they'll be run for the appropriate interaction points.

Hooks are run on the repository where the triggers are fired. If you register a `precommit` hook on your local repository, it will be triggered every time you make a commit.

Hooks are local, so they are not propagated when you clone a repository or push commits to another repository.

Comment: So, If I want to trigger a script everytime a push is made I can do it with the incoming hook on the remote repository.But wait !!! what is the use of incoming hook on my local repo (I am not going to use it anyway)?

Comment: @Mohanapriya: you really want to read the `hg help config` information, look for the *hooks* section. The `incoming` hook is *Run after a commit has been pulled, pushed, or unbundled into the local repository.*

Comment: Okay @Martijn Thanks